# Отладка Qt приложения в MSVC2015

Tags: qt, visual-c++

`Qt 5.6.1` установлен с помощью `MaintenanceTool`, студия `2015 update 2`.
Приложение собирается в Debug, подключены отладочные версии библиотек `Qt` (с окончанием `d`). Отладчик показывает (`Debug-Windows-Modules`), что pdb подгружены.
При пошаговой отладке не переходит в код библиотек `Qt` (студия пишет, что файл `.cpp` не найден и предлагает дальше в дизассемблере трассировать).
Есть ли вариант проходить отладчиком код библиотек без загрузки исходников?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Развёрнутый ответ на ваш вопрос найдёте в [этой статье](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yd4f8bd1(v=vs.90)). Если коротко, то нет, без исходников никак.

**UPD:**

> Файл базы данных программы (PDB) содержит отладочные данные и сведения
>   о состоянии проекта, позволяющие выполнять последовательную компоновку
>   отладочной конфигурации программы.
>
> При каждом создании OBJ-файла
>   компилятор C/C++ объединяет отладочные данные в VCx0.PBD. Вставляемые
>   в него данные включают сведения о типах, но не включают символьные
>   данные, такие как определения функций.